# Which font is it?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

I would know which font it is. Someone could tell me?

[image]

Comment: This is the the regular `\ttfamily` (from Computer Modern) font.

Comment: to use it in that form, what package I should use?

Comment: For *just* the font, use `\texttt{...}`, or the switch `{\ttfamily ...}`. For the colour formatting, you'll have to look into the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings). As it stands, this is a duplicate of [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)

Comment: Just look at the documentation of TikZ/PGF package. You can search your own texmf tree for the doc files it uses a custom listings-like structure.

Answer (score 1):

As **Werner** has mentioned, you can use the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package to produce a similar output; a little example (refer to the package documentation to learn all the customization possibilities it offers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{63,88,167}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{204,202,229}

\lstset{  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{myblue},
  morekeywords={addplot,coordinates,legend,axis,tikzpicture},
  backgroundcolor=\color{mygray},
  texcsstyle=*\color{black} 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major,width=6cm]
\addplot [thick,blue]
    coordinates {(1,0.0000001) (2,0.0065) (3,0.1) (4,0.9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]